# Decomposition of non-singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any way to show that a non-singular matrix A can be partitioned as follows:
\begin{eqnarray*}
A&=&\left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
\underset{\left( k\times k_{1}\right) }{{B}_{11}}\underset{\left(
k_{1}\times {n_{1}}\right) }{C_{1}} & \underset{\left( k\times
k_{2}\right) }{{B}_{12}}\underset{\left( k_{2}\times n_{2}\right) }{%
D_{1}} \\ 
\underset{\left( \left( n-k\right) \times \left( n_{1}-k_{1}\right)
\right) }{{B}_{21}}\underset{\left( \left( n_{1}-k_{1}\right)
\times n_{1}\right) }{C_{2}} & \underset{\left( \left(
n-k\right) \times \left( n_{2}-k_{2}\right) \right) }{{B}_{22}}\underset{%
\left( \left( n_{2}-k_{2}\right) \times n_{2}\right) }{D_{2}}%
\end{array}%
\right] 
\end{eqnarray*}

where $n=n_{1}+n_{2}, k=k_{1}+k_{2}$ and the matrices
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c}
 \left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
{{B}_{11}} & {{B}_{12}}%
\end{array}%
\right]  ,\text{  } 
 \left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
{{B}_{21}} & {{B}_{22}}%
\end{array}%
\right] 
\end{array}%
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
C_{1} \\ 
C_{2}%
\end{array}%
\right] ,\text{  }\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
D_{1}\\ 
D_{2}%
\end{array}%
\right]
\end{equation*}
are all non-singular square matrices?

Comment: Do you have a reason to think this is true? Have you tried some obvious seeming possible counterexamples such as the identity matrix? Also, are $n_1,n_2,k_1,k_2$ supposed to be given or free?